# How can i set ngb-pagination page lenght on table?

Tags: html, angular, pagination, components

I have a table on Angular, I have set a pagination for it, but I cannot limit the number of pages at the bottom. How can I provide this?

The part about pagination

```
<tr *ngFor="let obj of clientResults | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page -1) * pageSize + pageSize ;">
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
</tr>


<div class="col col-sm-6">
    <div class="text-sm-right float-sm-end listjs-pagination">
      <ngb-pagination
      [collectionSize]="clientResults.length" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize">
    </ngb-pagination>
    </div>
</div>
```

The part where the page and pageSize variables are defined

```
export class ClientResultComponent implements OnInit {
    public page = 1;
    public pageSize = 30;
    
}
```

This is the pagination I got. All pages are in a list. I want to limit it to 5 or 6 max because how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [Api NgbPagination docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/api#NgbPagination), you should look for this configuration

> maxSize
>
> The maximum number of pages to display.
> Type: number
>
> Default value: 0 — initialized from NgbPaginationConfig service

```
<ngb-pagination
    [collectionSize]="clientResults.length" 
    [(page)]="page" 
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [maxSize]="5">
</ngb-pagination>
```

[Demo Advanced pagination](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples#advanced)